# Can't reference Image ID in C# Code. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know, why I can't reference "asp:Image" (Image1) control in my code, but I can reference datalist control (DataList1) which contains asp:Image. Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div id="imageHolder">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"  RepeatColumns="4" Width="100%">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" OnDataBinding="DataList1_DataBinding"  Width="80%" Height="100px"
                CssClass="datalistImages" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "http://mywebsite.com/" + Eval("url") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>
</asp:Content>
```

And I'm 100% sure I'm working in the correct class. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot reference the imagem control because it is inside the `DataList` and every item has an imagem. What do you want to do with the image?

Comment: Actually I would like to get URL of every image that is displayed on website..

Comment: It should be easier to get all the URLs out of the datasource that is bound to the control than trying to iterate over all image controls generated by the data. `var urls = mydatasource.Select(o => o.url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's in the item collection.
If you want to reach that image control at real time you have to use ItemCreated or ItemDataBound events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Datalist events.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx